# How do I write a BufferedImage as a PNG with no compression?

Tags: java, png, javax.imageio

I need to write a `BufferedImage` as a .png with no compression performed.  I've looked around, and come up with the following code.

```
public void save(String outFilePath) throws IOException {
    Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png");
    ImageWriter writer = iter.next();

    File file = new File(outFilePath);      
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(file);
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    iwp.setCompressionQuality(1.0f);

    IIOImage image = new IIOImage(mapImage, null, null);

    writer.write(null, image, iwp);
    writer.dispose();

    //ImageIO.write(mapImage, "png", file);
}
```

Here's the exception being thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Compression not supported.
    at javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(Unknown Source)
    at Map.MapTransformer.save(MapTransformer.java:246)
    at Map.MapTransformer.main(MapTransformer.java:263)
```

Comment: if youre not going to be compressing it ... why not bmp?

Comment: Maybe you should be using MODE_DISABLED instead.

Comment: Also, the only downside to enabling compression on a `PNG` is a slightly costlier operation.  `PNG`s are lossless, so compression has no ill effects on image quality.

Comment: @CamHart : hey, could you tell us how did you solved issue ?I know it is asked quite long ago..

Comment: @CamHart have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG images achieve compression by first applying a prediction [filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html) (you can choose among five variants), and then compressing the prediction error with ZLIB. You cannot omit these two steps, what you can do is to specify "NONE" as prediction filter, and compressionLevel=0 for the ZLIB compression, which would roughly correspond to a non-compressed image. The `javax.imageio.*` package does not allow (I think) to select this parameters, perhaps you can try with [this](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/com/keypoint/PngEncoder.html) or [this](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/)