# java image compression for any image format(jpg, PNG, gif)

Tags: java

I am using the code given below for image compression of jpeg image.

```
File input = new File("digital_image_processing.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

File compressedImageFile = new File("compress.jpg");  
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

 Iterator<ImageWriter>writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
 ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

 ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
 writer.setOutput(ios);

 ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

 param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
 param.setCompressionQuality(0.05f);

 writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

But when I tried for for PNG format by changing ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png"); 
It is giving me error that compression not supported.

So how should i modify the above code so as to support all image format compression

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a BufferedImage as a PNG with no compression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318677/how-do-i-write-a-bufferedimage-as-a-png-with-no-compression)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it's a completely different problem

Comment: @dragon66 you are using almost exactly the same code and getting the same error, even though you're using that code for a different reason

Comment: @immibis: The OP used the same code and got the same error does not mean it's the same question.The one you quoted is seeking a way to avoid compression while this question want to find a way to uniformly set compression for all writers and I am trying to give the cause behind the exception

Comment: PNG is a format without compression, you can't compress a PNG image, if you want to compress PNG you must considerate change output format.

Comment: @dragon66 Sorry, I had confused me lossless compression with no compression. What I meant is that a (high) compressed PNG can not be compressed further and if you want to compress need to change the format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you used ImageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam(). From the following quote from ImageWriter.java:

> public ImageWriteParam getDefaultWriteParam()
>
> Returns a new ImageWriteParam object of the appropriate type for this
>   file format containing default values, that is, those values that
>   would be used if no ImageWriteParam object were specified. This is
>   useful as a starting point for tweaking just a few parameters and
>   otherwise leaving the default settings alone.
>
> The default implementation constructs and returns a new
>   ImageWriteParam object that does not allow tiling, progressive
>   encoding, or compression, and that will be localized for the current
>   Locale (i.e., what you would get by calling new
>   ImageWriteParam(getLocale()).
>
> Individual plug-ins may return an instance of ImageWriteParam with
>   additional optional features enabled, or they may return an instance
>   of a plug-in specific subclass of ImageWriteParam.

The actual behavior depends on individual implementation of specific ImageWriteParam. I believe the reason JPG image works is that the ImageWriteParam for JPG set the `canWriteCompressed` protected field for the default ImageWriteParam but for PNG image, for some reason it doesn't do that.

If you look at the com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageWriteParam.java, you will find it indeed doesn't set it.

In order to make your code work generally, you can do like this:

```
  File input = new File("digital_image_processing.jpg");
  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);

  File compressedImageFile = new File("compress.jpg");  
  OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

  Iterator<ImageWriter>writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
  ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();

  ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
  writer.setOutput(ios);

  ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
  // Check if canWriteCompressed is true
  if(param.canWriteCompressed()) {
     param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
     param.setCompressionQuality(0.05f);
  }
  // End of check
  writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param);
```

**Update:** I was trying to find out a way for you to fine-tune PNG image compression within the framework of ImageIO. But unfortunately, given the current implementation, it seems next to impossible. Java PNG writer plugin has fixed filtering - adaptive filtering and fixed deflater level - 9 which is the best thing it could do.

Comment: i tried with above code but in case of png image instead of decreasing size ,size of image is increasing

Comment: @AkshayYaduvanshi: the above code is just a workaround of the exception. The compression related settings have no effect for PNG images. The two factors governing PNG file size are: the first stage of filtering the raw data, then the second stage of deflate compressing the filtered data. There are four types of filtering choices and you can even mix the four adaptively. For deflate compression, you can set the deflate level from 0-9. The larger, the higher compression rate, but the slower it is.

Comment: @AkshayYaduvanshi: The original image you read may have been optimized using other tools (you will find a lot tools for that purpose). And when you using the default setting to save it back to PNG, it's very likely the size will increase.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code that can compress image jpg and png to smaller size.

Sample Image

1. Original Image (png) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlC5w.jpg (Size:923kb)
2. Compressed Image (PNG): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p4TW.jpg (Size:48.9kb, Compression Quality : 0.35f)

public ByteArrayOutputStream compressedImage(BufferedImage originalImage,Float compressValue, String fileType) throws IOException {

```
ByteArrayOutputStream compressed = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try (ImageOutputStream outputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(compressed)) {
        
    ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("JPEG").next();
        
    ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();

    //to handle image png to get same output as original file with smaller size
    if(fileType.equals("jpg")){
    
        jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(compressValue);
        jpgWriter.setOutput(outputStream);
        jpgWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(originalImage, null, null), jpgWriteParam);
        jpgWriter.dispose();

    }
    else{

        BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(
        originalImage.getWidth(),
        originalImage.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);

        newBufferedImage.createGraphics()
        .drawImage(newBufferedImage, 0, 0, Color.white, null);

        Graphics2D g2d = newBufferedImage.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, newBufferedImage.getWidth(), newBufferedImage.getHeight());
        g2d.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        //fix colour  
        // int[] rgb = originalImage.getRGB(0, 0, originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), null, 0, originalImage.getWidth());
        // newBufferedImage.setRGB(0, 0, originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), rgb, 0, originalImage.getWidth());

        //fix colour 
        // newBufferedImage = this.fixBadImageJPEG(newBufferedImage);
        
        newBufferedImage.flush();

        jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(compressValue);

        jpgWriter.setOutput(outputStream);
        jpgWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(newBufferedImage, null, null), jpgWriteParam);
        jpgWriter.dispose();

    }

}


return compressed;
```

}